# Mean of quotient vs quotient of the sum of numerator and the sum of denominator

Tags: inequality, percentages

Prove or disprove the following inequality.

$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^n b_i} \geq \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i} \right),
$$

where $a_i \leq b_i$ for all $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$.

I am actually computing the average of some percentages $(a_i / b_i)$ and for some reasons I cannot compute it directly. I can only do the fraction on the left. I am trying to establish this inequality so that I know what I can expect from the computation.

Comment: $a_1=1=a_2$, $b_1=1,b_2=2$. LHS=$2/3$, RHS=$3/4$

Comment: Averaging percentages and averaging averages is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: See also [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#Kidney_stone_treatment).

Comment: The inequality is true if $a_i/b_i$ and $b_i$ are ordered similarly, if they are opposite, it's the other way around.  So it matters a lot how you pair the $(a_i, b_i)$. Look up  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality